# Recharts: Different gradient for each bar in barchart

Tags: reactjs, bar-chart, gradient, recharts

How is it possible to have different gradient color for each bar like this?
[image]

I could give different solid color for each bar by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65636948/7504437). I tried to include `<lineargradient>` component inside the map function and set `stopcolor` according to the index. But could not achieve it. Seems like I have to define the `<lineargradient>` component outside the `<Bar>` component.

This is the code I tried:

```
const barColors = [ '#4c5f7c', '#dc2424', '#fcda00', '#8383ba', '#23dbbd' ];

<Bar dataKey='pv' radius={40}>
 {data.map((entry, index) => (
  <React.Fragment>
   <defs>
    <linearGradient id='colorUv' x1='0' y1='0' x2='100%' y2='0' spreadMethod='reflect'>
     <stop offset='0' stopColor='#1a1a1a' />
     <stop offset='1' stopColor={barColors[index]} />
     </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <Cell key={`cell-${index}`} fill='url(#colorUv)' />
   </React.Fragment>
  ))}
 <LabelList dataKey='pv' position='insideRight' fill='#f5f5f5' />
 <LabelList dataKey='name' position='insideLeft' fill='#f5f5f5' />
</Bar>
```

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution:

```
<BarChart width={600} height={300} data={data} layout='vertical'margin={top:5,right:30,left:20,bottom:5}}>
 <XAxis type='number' hide={true} />
 <YAxis type='category' dataKey='name' hide={true} />
 <defs>
  {barColors.map((color, index) => (
   <linearGradient id={`colorUv${index}`} x1='0' y1='0' x2='100%' y2='0' spreadMethod='reflect'>
    <stop offset='0' stopColor='#1a1a1a' />
    <stop offset='1' stopColor={color} />
   </linearGradient>
  ))}
 </defs>

 <Bar dataKey='pv' radius={40}>
  {data.map((entry, index) => (
   <Cell key={`cell-${index}`} fill={`url(#colorUv${index})`} />
  ))}
  <LabelList dataKey='pv' position='insideRight' fill='#f5f5f5' />
  <LabelList dataKey='name' position='insideLeft' fill='#f5f5f5' />
 </Bar>
</BarChart>
```