# Recharts: style each bar according to index or css

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, recharts

I want to style each recharts odd bar with opacity 0.6% if a certain state is true (isInDefaultStack). To date, I have not found a way to access the index of the bar and apply a fill or use e.g. styled-components and pass a prop to set opacity. Note, the function `legendColor` just gets the right color.

```js
const muteColor = (hexColor, opacity = 0.6) => {
  return hexToRGB(hexColor, opacity);
};

const color = isInDefaultStack
  ? legendColor(dataKey)
  : muteColor(legendColor(dataKey));

<ResponsiveContainer width={widthChart} height={heightChart}>
  <ComposedChart data={isInDefaultStack ? [...budgetData] : [...chartData]}>
    <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
    <XAxis dataKey={"yearLabel"} />
    <YAxis width={90} />
    <ReLegend
      iconSize={12}
      content={<CustomLegend disabled={["opportunity"]} />}
    />
    <Bar
      barSize={barSize}
      name={name}
      dataKey={fullDataKey}
      fill={color}
      key={`${dataKey}-${stackId}`}
    ></Bar>
  </ComposedChart>
</ResponsiveContainer>
```

Below is my attempt to use styled-components and then the above code would then have the `<BarStyled>` instead of `<Bar>` Component

```js
import styled from 'styled-components'
import {Bar} from 'recharts';

const BarStyled = styled(Bar)`
opacity: ${({isInDefaultStack}) => isInDefaultStack ? '0.6' : '1'}`;

<BarStyled isInDefaultStack={isInDefaultStack}
```

Note: I have also tried using css (withStlyes) and applying a className to the ResponsiveContainer but this doesnt work unless i click on the bar (i.e. when bar renders for the first time, it applies opacity to all bars, and then by clicking on any bar, the opacity then only works on each odd bar:

```js
<ResponsiveContainer className={isInDefaultStack ? chartRoot : ''}...

const ChartStyles = {
  chartRoot: {
    '& > div > svg > g > g > g:nth-child(odd)': {opacity: '0.6'},
  },
}
```

any ideas, and is there any way to access the Index of a Barchart???

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution and you can also see it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65636364/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-each-bar-in-recharts).
--> Before closing the `</Bar>` component, map through the array of data and use the index of the map to get the index of the bar using the recharts 'Cell' Component.

```js
<Bar
//...
>
  {isInDefaultStack
    ? budgetData.map((data, i) => (
        <Cell fill={i % 2 == 0 ? opaqueColor : color} />
      ))
    : null}
</Bar>
```