# displaying clustered bar graphs instead of single bars

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea, recharts

i am new to react js and migrating from php to react js

i am trying to replicate bar graphs like in php and chart js combination like below

[image]

but i am troubling to create bar graphs

**Dashboard.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { BarChart, Bar, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Tooltip, Legend, PieChart, Pie, Cell } from 'recharts';
import Service from '../services/Service'

const Dashboard = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            alert("Fetichng data calling...");
            const result = Service.fetchData();
            alert("Fetichng data calling.done.."+JSON.stringify(result));

            setData(result);

            alert("Fetichng data calling..11111.Done!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
        };

        fetchData();
    }, []);

    const COLORS = ['#8884d8', '#82ca9d', '#ffc658', '#ff7f0e'];

    return (
        <div>
            <HeaderComponent />

            <h2>Smishing Dashboard</h2>

            {data ? (
                <>
                    <h3>Bar Chart</h3>
                    <BarChart width={600} height={400} data={Object.entries(data).map(([label, value]) => ({ label, value }))}>
                        <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
                        <XAxis dataKey="label" />
                        <YAxis />
                        <Tooltip />
                        <Legend />
                        {Object.entries(data).map(([label, value], index) => (
                            <Bar
                                key={`bar-${index}`}
                                dataKey="value"
                                fill={COLORS[index % COLORS.length]}
                            />
                        ))}
                    </BarChart>
                    {}
                </>
            ) : (
                <p>Loading data...</p>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

this is how bar graph displaying using above code

[image]

Since i am new am unable to fix it please help me

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65636364/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-each-bar-in-recharts